# What's the best way to define a BOM in gradle without involving XML?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

XML being one of the reasons people move to Gradle, our project defines several pom packaged items. I assume that these are BOM's since they just used to pull in dependencies. So... how do you define a BOM in Gradle from a "best practices" / no XML perspective?  I know that you can create a configuration that has dependencies and then just include it but I don't, for example, want "gradle build" to create a jar file for this sub-project as it would be pointless and slow down my build for no good reason. Am I on the right track or is there a better way and if so, what is it? Do I just turn off the jar creation somehow?

Comment: Confused; I don't see at all the part played by the BOM here. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: What type of BOM are we talking about?  Somehow I don't think you mean [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: I edited the byte-order-mark tag off the question. "A bom is a special kind of pom that is used to control the versions of a project’s dependencies and provides a central place to define and update those versions." (https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/23/better-dependency-management-for-gradle) This article discusses using a Maven BOM within Gradle. I think the poster is asking about defining the equivalent in Gradle for use in Gradle.

Comment: @KenGeis Bingo! This is a build discussion and BOM stands for Bill Of Materials in that parlance. "spring-framework-bom" is the common example used.

Comment: @KenGeis Oh, I see. Bad tag. I figured BOM was Bill Of Materials, of course. What are the downvotes for though?

Comment: There's https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin

Comment: @tim_yates I've been looking at that, of course. It doesn't seem to do what I need which is to define a structure that can be used as a BOM within Gradle, rather than allow the use of one that already exists within Maven. If I'm wrong, show me where, but I don't think so. Closest I've found is a means by which you can create an array or list of dependencies. IDK how I would pass that around though and I lost track of the reference since then.

Comment: @user447607, downvotes indicate that someone didn't like the question. Maybe it was because of the improper tagging (it was already downvoted when I removed that tag.) Maybe it would be more liked if you update it with the links in these comments and explain how those are not what you are looking to do. Include some breaks in the text, and explain what a BOM is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what I need. It's from right out of the Gradle User Guild in Chapter 52. Specifically it's Example 52.16. "Collections and arrays of dependencies".

```
List groovy = ["org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4@jar",
               "commons-cli:commons-cli:1.0@jar",
               "org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.4@jar"]
List hibernate = ['org.hibernate:hibernate:3.0.5@jar',
                  'somegroup:someorg:1.0@jar']
dependencies {
    runtime groovy, hibernate
}
```